# How to remove time from long date

Tags: notepad++

```
0.00016794,0.06717899,11/25/2017 3:27:04 PM,11/26/2017 1:16:51 AM
0.00016636,0.06656090,11/30/2017 11:34:16 PM,11/30/2017 11:35:15 PM
```

I have tried use this `\/2017.*?,` but it would only removed the first time on each line.

Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=2017).+?M`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=2017)   : lookbehind, zero-length assertion, make sure we have 2017 before current position
.+?         : 1 or more any character, not greedy
M           : literally "M"
```

**Result for given example:**

```
0.00016794,0.06717899,11/25/2017,11/26/2017 
0.00016636,0.06656090,11/30/2017,11/30/2017
```

Comment: @RickyKSK: You're welcome, glad it helps.